# media query with div display property

Tags: css, media-queries

Here's the css for a random div object:

```
.titleHome {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 12px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

When the screen width reaches over 900px, I want the display of this object to be `none`, and I want it to be visible below 900px. I tried the following media-query but it doesn't work:

```
(first change css to have display: none;)
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    .titleHome { 
        display: normal; 
    }
}
```

However I noticed that if I leave the css the way it is above, and use the following, it works:

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    .titleHome { 
        display: none; 
    }
}
```

However this is the opposite of what I need. How can I make the div disappear when screen width is less than 900px?

Comment: `display: normal` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Normal` is not a valid keyword. You should use `block` for your case.

```
  @media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    .titleHome { 
        display: block; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: wow, didn't realize it was that easy, my visual-studio gives me `normal` as an option

Answer (score 0):

Change `max-width` to `min-width`.

```
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
    .titleHome { 
        display: none; 
    }
}
```